# How to select a value if it is given in range format?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with one of the columns representing age. The value of age is given as intervals as shown in the table below:

```
head(ddd)
country.of.birth age     sex    X2000 X2001 X2002 X2003 X2004 X2005 X2006 X2007
Afghanistan      0-4     men       0     0     1     2     2     0     1     1
Afghanistan      5-9     women     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     0
Afghanistan      10-14   men       0     2     5     2     3     4     1     1
Afghanistan      15-19   women     4     1     4     2     3     2     3     2
Afghanistan      20-24   men       5     0     8     7     7     3     5     3
Afghanistan      25-29   women     4     8     3     9     4     4     4     3
```

What command should I use to be able to select a certain age range? I tried:

```
sum(ddd[ddd$age == "20-24", 4:11])
```

to get the sum of all columns with an age in the range of 20-24 (should give 38), I got this error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

Comment: What is the output of `sapply(ddd, class)`?

Comment: Here is the output:

`sapply(ddd, class)
  country       age       sex     X2000     X2001     X2002     X2003     X2004 
 "factor"  "factor"  "factor" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" 
    X2005     X2006     X2007     X2008     X2009     X2010     X2011     X2012 
"integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" 
    X2013     X2014 
"integer" "integer"`

Comment: @akrun
`sum(subset(ddd, age=='20-24', select=4:11))

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables`

Comment: Why do you get "country" from `sapply`? It should be "country.of.birth" .

Comment: I edited the name, sorry.

Comment: @Pascal
Age is a factor as sapply shows, can this be the problem?

Comment: No, it is not the problem.

Comment: To check for possible extra spaces, what do you get with `head(nchar(ddd$age))`

Comment: `head(nchar(ddd$age))
Error in nchar(ddd$age) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector`

Comment: @akrun
I checked your answer. I commented below your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume this to be a case of trailing/leading spaces.  We can remove the trailing/leading spaces with `str_trim` from `stringr)

```
ddd$age[5] <- '20-29 '
sum(ddd[ddd$age == "20-29", 4:11])
#Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
# only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

library(stringr)
sum(ddd[str_trim(ddd$age)=='20-29', 4:11])
#[1] 38
```

Or use `sub`

```
 ddd$age <- sub('^\\s*|\\s*$', '', ddd$age)
 sum(ddd[str_trim(ddd$age)=='20-29', 4:11])
 #[1] 38
```

If you use `grep`, this problem can be avoided

```
 sum(ddd[grep('20-29', ddd$age),4:11])
 #[1] 38
```

Comment: This is most likely the issue. Especially with this survey style data +1

Comment: I checked the cvs file. There is a trailing single space after each interval. That is there is a single space after 24 in the 20-24 interval. `str_trim(ddd$age) did the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be that some columns are factors

temp$X2000 <- as.factor(temp$X2000)

sum(temp[temp$age=="20-24",4:11])

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...)

temp$X2000 <- as.numeric(temp$X2000)

sum(temp[temp$age=="20-24",4:11])

37

Comment: It is not the reason.  I checked it.

Comment: They are not. See the comments.